# Calling a C macro from another macro function

Tags: c, macros

I have a macro defined as below. This is used to print debugging information to the console. Now, I have to send this debugs over to a socket without disturbing the existing code. I am thinking of
changing this so that the `Debug_Print` macro would check if it is in socket mode and call a different macro to send it over the socket.  I tried `dprintf` and it works for my purpose. How can I change this `Debug_Print` macro so that it calls `printf(...)` vs `dprintf(fd, ...)`  by checking `is_in_socket_mode()`?

`bool is_in_socket_mode()` function would tell if it is in socket mode.

Existing macro:

```
#define Debug_Print(label, ...) ( Is_Enabled(label) ? (void)printf(__VA_ARGS__) : (void)0 )
```

I tried to use `is_in_socket_mode()` in the existing macro, but I am not able to figure out how to do this. I believe I have to introduce another macro and call that within the `Debug_Print` macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit about terminology: macros are instantiated at compile time. At runtime they do not exist anymore, so "calling a macro" in the sense of calling a function is not possible.

Since `is_in_socket_mode()` is a run-time function, this should be a question of checking its value in the macro:

```
#define Debug_Print(label, ...) ( Is_Enabled(label) ? ((is_in_socket_mode()) ? (void)dprintf(fd, __VA_ARGS__) : (void)printf(__VA_ARGS__)) : (void)0 )
```